# unused import statement in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a file called views.py, and in it there is this line: from django.shortcuts import render, which is marked as an unused import statement.
I've ooked around and found the shortcuts.py file, but for some reason pycharm still marks my import statement as unused.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well is `render` used anywhere in the `views.py` file?

If not, then PyCharm is correctly identifying the unused import, and you should remove that line.

If it is used, then I'll need more info.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm marks import lines as unused, if the names provided by these imports are not used in the code below. You can delete these lines and this will not affect the behavior of the program.

Comment: "You can delete these lines and this will not affect the behavior of the program." **This is not always true.** An imported library may be used by another imported one to achieve a plugin-like architecture. In this case while the code in the file does not directly use anything from the library, removing it will possibly cause the script to malfunction. An example of a library such as this I've used recently is `pillow-avif-plugin`, and this causes an annoying, spurious unused import warning. In that case the solution is to prefix the import with `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` .

Comment: @Kryomaani, yes, you are right. But this is an example of bad architecture. In a good way, after explicitly importing the libraries, it would be worth accessing each of them and explicitly obtaining the object of interest. After this, pass the list of all plugin objects to the “plugins” manager.